# How to test if time is 13000

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to make it so a villager will teleport home when the time is 13000. Here's what I got:

```
/time query daytime 13000
```

With a comparator got to a command block with this in it:

```
/tp @e[type=Villager,name=Wizard] -685 56 510
```

But it doesn't tp the villager when the time is 13000!

Comment: You probably want to be using 1.9, and if you are using 1.9, why are you using a comparator?

Comment: I'm not using 1.9 YET I will.